# always ask for login when download file from public Bintray repo

Tags: bintray, ojo

I'm not sure it's the right place to ask for tech support. But please route me to the correct contacts if I'm wrong.

Here is the issue, TestNG Team hosts the TestNG Eclipse plugin on Bintray.com, today suddenly people complain that they can't install the plugins, it always asks for login, e.g. url: https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/.
is there any change at Bintray.com side that we need to follow?

There is a related issue on github: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/334

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here. However, you may find better luck [SoftwareRecs.SE](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Comment: You better contact the service desk of the company offering that service, not much any of us can do a thing about it, except that this question will probably collect *me too!* answers.

Comment: TestNG is open source test framework, Bintray.com is free for open source projects, but not commercial supporting service at all. My question is very clear, 1) either somebody can suggest what's going on Bintray that asking for login when download (it happened all suddenly, all works great before), 2) if somebody happen to know support contact of Bintray.com for open source project, that'd be great as well.

Answer (score 0):

this ticket can be closed since the Bintray.com restore back to normal, no login prompt any more.